# Weird output when iterating over a python list and change characters in it

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a List called `screenName` with its input being:

```
[['107492.öeso2'], ['106268.test4'], ['106239.test3'], ['106216.test2'], ['106190.test1']]
```

I now have this code to iterate over every letter and remove it until it reaches a dot

```
for o in screenName:
    for e in o:
        for l in e:
            if l.isdigit():
                e = e.replace(l, '')
            elif l == '.':
                e = e.replace(l, '')
            elif l.isalpha():
                break
        print(e)
```

The problem now is that the output is this:

```
öeso
test4
test
test
test
```

When I expected something like this:

```
öeso2
test4
test3
test2
test1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Surely `for o in screenName:  for e in o:  print(e[e.index('.') + 1:])` is more readable?

Comment: the problem is you use replace without limit… there is cleaner ways to achieve your goal just like deepspace comment

Comment: Consider the first string, `'107492.öeso2'`, when you get to the first `'2'`, you do use `e = e.replace(l, '')` where `l == '2'`, so that removes *all occurrences of `'2'` from the string*

Comment: @DeepSpace yeah, I'd go with `e.partition('.')[-1]`

Comment: Regex should also work well: `[[re.sub(r"^\d+\.", "", e) for e in o] for o in screenName]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first item in your list is ['107492.öeso2'].
So whenever it encounters a digit, it replaces it with a blank (''). However, as soon as it encounters the digit '2', it replaces all the instances of '2's with blanks.
That is why your resultant output is "öeso" and not "öeso2".

Instead of using the replace method, you can use the string slicing method.

The code would go as follows:

```
for o in screenName:
    for e in o:
        for l in range(len(e)):
            if e[l] == '.':
                e = e[l+1:]
                break
        print(e)
```

Hope this helped. Have a nice day.

Comment: The explanation is correct, but your suggestion won't work properly, too. Slicing away characters while iterating over the length of the string is a bad idea (that part actually worked better in OP's code). Instead, just split by the `.` or use `re.sub`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm really new to python to be honest.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to slice a string while iterating over its length? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Actually I misread what your code is doing. Since you only slice once and then break from the loop, it's fine (although `split` would probably still be better).